# What is happening in this Assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, att, sign-extension

**Background**: I am doing a "binary bomb" assignment in which I must pass 6 different phases to 'defuse' the bomb. I can use a debugger to help keep track of values and step through each line of the Assembly. I am stuck on the second phase.

**Goal**: Find the 'password' for this phase that satisfy the following program. The correct password will move me on to the next phase

**What I think I know**: It looks like right away, it's trying to read in 6 numbers. When I disassembled the main() function of the entire bomb, I noticed the a line with "%d %d %d %d %d %d" so this phase must require 6 numbers. Also, it looks like there's a loop starting at 1 and ending after the counter is greater than 5. It seems to being tracked in the -0x4(%rbp) part of memory. It looks like at  line, it compares what is being tracked in %eax to what is entered by the user(earlier stored in %edx at line  to see if they're equal. If they aren't, the bomb will explode. If they are, it'll continue through the loop.

```
0x400ec9 <phase_2>:     push   %rbp
0x400eca <phase_2+1>:   mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x400ecd <phase_2+4>:   sub    $0x30,%rsp
0x400ed1 <phase_2+8>:   mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
0x400ed5 <phase_2+12>:  lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rsi
0x400ed9 <phase_2+16>:  mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdi
0x400edd <phase_2+20>:  callq  0x4013e9 <read_six_numbers>
0x400ee2 <phase_2+25>:  mov    -0x20(%rbp),%eax
0x400ee5 <phase_2+28>:  test   %eax,%eax
0x400ee7 <phase_2+30>:  jns    0x400eee <phase_2+37>
0x400ee9 <phase_2+32>:  callq  0x401983 <explode_bomb>
0x400eee <phase_2+37>:  movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x400ef5 <phase_2+44>:  jmp    0x400f1f <phase_2+86>
0x400ef7 <phase_2+46>:  mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x400efa <phase_2+49>:  cltq
0x400efc <phase_2+51>:  mov    -0x20(%rbp,%rax,4),%edx
0x400f00 <phase_2+55>:  mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x400f03 <phase_2+58>:  sub    $0x1,%eax
0x400f06 <phase_2+61>:  cltq
0x400f08 <phase_2+63>:  mov    -0x20(%rbp,%rax,4),%eax
0x400f0c <phase_2+67>:  add    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x400f0f <phase_2+70>:  add    $0x1,%eax
0x400f12 <phase_2+73>:  cmp    %eax,%edx
0x400f14 <phase_2+75>:  je     0x400f1b <phase_2+82>
0x400f16 <phase_2+77>:  callq  0x401983 <explode_bomb>
0x400f1b <phase_2+82>:  addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x400f1f <phase_2+86>:  cmpl   $0x5,-0x4(%rbp)
0x400f23 <phase_2+90>:  jle    0x400ef7 <phase_2+46>
0x400f25 <phase_2+92>:  leaveq
0x400f26 <phase_2+93>:  retq
```

**What I don't know**: There are some new instructions here I'm not familiar with. 'cltq' apparently performs "sign-extend %eax to %rax" but I'm not really sure what that means in this case. Also, I don't understand the line 'mov -0x20(%rbp, %rax, 4), %edx' and what it does exactly. I understand it's moving what's stored in 0x20 to the %rdx register, but I don't know what should be in that spot in memory at that time. I know when doing my debugging, %rbp at -0x20 holds one of the 6 values I entered. But I'm not really sure what %rax and 4 do exactly.

If someone can see what the 6 numbers required are, GREAT! If not, I hope someone can at least shed some light on this code and the problems I'm having to help nudge me in the right direction! Thanks

Some wrong solutions I tested:
1 2 3 4 5 6; 
10 20 30 40 50 60

(I didn't want to keep trying because each time I explode the bomb, I get a point off the assignment grade)

Comment: See [this link](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) for an explanation of the `-0x20(%rbp, %rax, 4)` syntax. Basically it is equivalent to an array access where each member has 4 bytes (hence the 4) and `%rax` is the index of the array while `%rbp` is the address. I'm not sure what the `-0x20` does but I assume it's an offset of some sort that is just added to the final address...

Comment: @nonsensickle I just stepped in that line with the debugger and displayed info on the registers. %rax says it contains "0x1" or just "1". So this is probably a stupid question, but does that mean it's "1*4" value which would = 4 or it's still just 1 but stored in that array?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But remember that in C this is done for you automatically. Integers tend to be stored as 32 bit numbers (meaning 4 bytes) so if you have an array of them and you have the address of the first integer then you have to add 4 to get the next one and add 4 to get the one after that...

Comment: This notation lets you say how big each item in your *array* is. So you say this is my start address, I want the 3rd element and each element is 4 bytes long. So you go compute what address you need to fetch it for me (which will be the address + 3 * 4 = address + 12)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I can break this code...

I've tried to turn this into C code, so here goes:

```
void read_six_numbers(int *array);
void explode();

int phase_2()
{
    int array[6];

    read_six_numbers(array);

    if (array[0] < 0)
    {
        explode();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        int cur  = array[i];   // %edx
        int prev = array[i-1]; // %eax

        prev += i;
        prev++;

        if (prev != cur)
        {
            explode();
        }
    }
}
```

So to pass the test you will need the following sequence of numbers:

```
n, n + 2, (n + 2) + 3, ((n + 2) + 3) + 4, (((n + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5, ((((n + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5) + 6
```

or

```
n, n + 2, n + 5, n + 9, n + 14, n + 20
```

Where `n` is a positive number or zero.

Here are my annotations of your assembly code:

```
0x400ec9 <phase_2>:     push   %rbp
0x400eca <phase_2+1>:   mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x400ecd <phase_2+4>:   sub    $0x30,%rsp          // Reserve some space on the stack...
0x400ed1 <phase_2+8>:   mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
0x400ed5 <phase_2+12>:  lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rsi   // Compute the address of -0x20(%rbp) and store it in %rsi (I'm assuming this is an argument for read_six_numbers below)
0x400ed9 <phase_2+16>:  mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdi
0x400edd <phase_2+20>:  callq  0x4013e9 <read_six_numbers>
0x400ee2 <phase_2+25>:  mov    -0x20(%rbp),%eax       // From the code this looks like an array. Load its first element.
0x400ee5 <phase_2+28>:  test   %eax,%eax              // bitwise and that sets the flags.
0x400ee7 <phase_2+30>:  jns    0x400eee <phase_2+37>  // Jump not signed (jump if positive), so we can deduce Rule 1: First number is positive!
0x400ee9 <phase_2+32>:  callq  0x401983 <explode_bomb> // Explode!
0x400eee <phase_2+37>:  movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)         // -0x4(%rbp) looks like a counter that starts at one so I'll call it `int i = 0;`
0x400ef5 <phase_2+44>:  jmp    0x400f1f <phase_2+86>   // Goto loop condition!
0x400ef7 <phase_2+46>:  mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax         // Loop body:
0x400efa <phase_2+49>:  cltq   // Extend sign for %eax (converts %eax [int32] to %rax [int64])
0x400efc <phase_2+51>:  mov    -0x20(%rbp,%rax,4),%edx // Our read values are in an array located at -0x20(%rbp) I'll call it array from now on. So this line ends up being %edx = array[i]
0x400f00 <phase_2+55>:  mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax         // reset i back to it's last value...
0x400f03 <phase_2+58>:  sub    $0x1,%eax               // Subtract 1 from i (are we checking our values backwards?)
0x400f06 <phase_2+61>:  cltq
0x400f08 <phase_2+63>:  mov    -0x20(%rbp,%rax,4),%eax // Load array[i] into %eax
0x400f0c <phase_2+67>:  add    -0x4(%rbp),%eax         // Add i to this value? Nice trick...
0x400f0f <phase_2+70>:  add    $0x1,%eax
0x400f12 <phase_2+73>:  cmp    %eax,%edx
0x400f14 <phase_2+75>:  je     0x400f1b <phase_2+82>
0x400f16 <phase_2+77>:  callq  0x401983 <explode_bomb>
0x400f1b <phase_2+82>:  addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x400f1f <phase_2+86>:  cmpl   $0x5,-0x4(%rbp)         // Loop condition: Check i against 5.
0x400f23 <phase_2+90>:  jle    0x400ef7 <phase_2+46>   // If i <= 5 goto Loop body
0x400f25 <phase_2+92>:  leaveq
0x400f26 <phase_2+93>:  retq
```

Comment: Should be `i <= 5` due to the `jle` and as such the last number is also checked. The comment in your assembly is correct, but the C code and the solution is wrong.

Comment: So I could try a solution such as: 1 3 8 17 31 50  ? I know @Jester above says it is not the right C code so I'm afraid to try this because of possibly being penalized.

Comment: It's a reverse engineering challenge, the first step should have been to disable the bomb as such ... not a terribly difficult thing, that. Just put a breakpoint on `explode_bomb` and don't let it continue. Then you can try as many inputs as you want. You can also disable networking of course. You can also just assemble this single function and comment out the `explode_bomb` calls or use a placeholder.

Comment: So if I set a breakpoint at explode_bomb, if it breaks after I try an input, that means the input failed? And then just don't continue from there and quit(q) and retry?

Comment: @Jester thanks for the correction, you're right! I've updated it.

Comment: @nonsensickle You were correct with your answer! I typed in '0 2 5 9 14 20' and I was able to pass this phase. I initially viewed your solution where 'n' value is being stored after each loop, so I tried an answer like '0 2 7 16 30 50' which didn't work. Thank you much in helping me understand how to translate Assembly back in to C code. Should help me in attempting the third phase.